# 1994 Chevrolet S10 2.2L LS pickup - gas smell when starting

Tags: chevrolet, fuel-system, troubleshooting, s10

Engine has just been rebuilt. Replaced the fuel filter, gas cap, and EGR as well. I can smell gas outside when starting and when shut off. There are no visible gas leaks coming from the gas tank.

Could it be a fuel line or fuel injector?

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the carbon canister?

Answer (score 1):

I would follow the path from the tank to the intake, just like for an electrical problem I'd start at the battery and work out. Might try working in reverse if that's easier, since the fuel path is a bit more straightforward and the engine side might be more accessible than the tank side.

It could be anywhere there isn't a good seal. Hard to say more than that with this info. :/